# Upgrading GCC on CentOS

Tags: linux, installation, centos, gcc

I need to upgrade GCC. When I type yum install GCC it tells me `Package gcc-4.1.2-51.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. Unfortunately I'm trying to install some software which requires GCC 4.3 minimum.

I checked out the possibility of installing GCC from source, but it looks very complicated!

How can I upgrade GCC to at least version 4.3 on CentOS?

Comment: If you want to update the system gcc you should first establish that this will break nothing that relies on it.

Comment: Like what, for example?

Comment: GCC is just a compiler right? So why would applications use it. I thought it was just for compiling sources?

Comment: I am not entirely sure with Centos, but Centos expects system files to be the version that is issued - I would just add the "will it break stuff" query to your question so it gets addressed as well as the howto

Comment: Yes it is just a compiler, some distributions will recompile some updates.

Comment: Indeed, however certain applications require a minimum version of GCC to build successfully due to available features or known bugs in previous versions. Additionally, in theory anyway, a newer version of GCC is more likely to build a more efficient executable as the compiler designers improve and tweak the build processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS 5.x has the "gcc44" package containing GCC version 4.4.

Comment: +1 - This is the workaround I have been using on my boxes, however it will require manual intervention in the future when 4.4 is moved into the main CentOS GCC rpm.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Remi's repository](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en). It usually has more up to date packages than the normal CentOS repository.

Comment: While Remi's repo has some good updates, it tends to focus on the PHP/MySQL ecosystem.  It happens that there are no GCC updates there for CentOS 5 or 6.